# Obtaining a list of words from a GNU aspell dictionary

Tags: internationalization, aspell

I downloaded the aspell package for Bengali language dictionary support. From the tarball, I was able to isolate the bn.wl file, which is simply a list of about 100,000 words, one on each line.

The problem is that the encoding is apparently is13194-bn, and any text editor I open the file with is showing garbage (one garbage-word per line). It's probably expecting utf8 or something.

How can I convert this file to readable form? I tried using iconv but it apparently can't recognize the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

aspell -l bn dump master

This works!